# Firebase is there any way to sign out both platform web and mobile app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Can I let the user sign out both web and mobile app simultaneously so that once signed out from web app, no longer be able to login to mobile app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres no way to logout someone on different devices but you have a few options, just requires putting some elements together.

You could [revoke the users refresh tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) which would mean when the token expires and the sdk goes to refresh it couldn't and would log out the user.

```
// Revoke all refresh tokens for a specified user for whatever reason.
// Retrieve the timestamp of the revocation, in seconds since the epoch.
admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
    .then(() => {
      return admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000;
    })
    .then((timestamp) => {
      console.log("Tokens revoked at: ", timestamp);
  });
```

You could also put a flag in the firebase realtime database and then when they reopen the app on their other devices, if logged in they could read the flag and do the logout on the client. Also if they had the web/mobile app open you could log them out in that way if they are listening for that flag at all times.

```
var logoutRef = firebase.database().ref('userLogoutRef/' + userUid);
logoutRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val() === true) {
      firebase.auth().signOut()
  }
});
```

You would just want to make sure you remove this flag on a subsequent login so a user can login.

Comment: You could use the same flag to also (in Firebase server-side security rules) deny the user further access to the database. This approach is blacklisting the user, so the node you store them in is typically called `/blacklist` or `/bannedUsers`.